# Is there any way to make a PopupWindow in android only dissapear when you don't press for longer?

Tags: android, kotlin, popupwindow

I'm working on a popup to display some basic bluetooth device information using PopupWindow, but I've ran into a problem. Every touch makes the popup dissapear, while some other apps have popups that do not dissapear if you keep holding down touch, which is what I'd like to achieve.

This is my current code:

```
private fun showDetails() {
        val inflater: LayoutInflater = activity?.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val popupView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_tigerbuilder_details, null)
        popupView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tgrbdetdevice_name).text = device.name
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
            popupView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tgrbdetdevice_nickname).text = device.alias
            popupView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tgrbdetdevice_nickname).visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        popupView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tgrbdetdevice_mac).text = device.address

        // create the popup window
        val width: Int = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        val height: Int = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        val focusable = true
        val popupWindow = PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable)
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        popupWindow.setIgnoreCheekPress()
        popupWindow.animationStyle = -1

        // show the popup window
        // which view you pass in doesn't matter, it is only used for the window tolken
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(view?.parent as View, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)

        popupWindow.dimBehind()

        popupView.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("Fragment", it.id.toString())
        }
    }
```

```
/**
 * Dim the background when PopupWindow shows
 */
fun PopupWindow.dimBehind() {
    val container = contentView.rootView
    val context = contentView.context
    val wm = context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    val p = container.layoutParams as WindowManager.LayoutParams
    p.flags = p.flags or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND
    p.dimAmount = 0.6f
    wm.updateViewLayout(container, p)
}
```